# How to get Letsencrypt ssl certificate for local iis web server using local DNS server Bind9

Tags: networking, server, dns, ssl, letsencrypt

I need help regarding for my iis web server in windows 10 Pro. I am using local DNS server bind9 to resolve the domain name and it works very well. But the problem is i am not able to generate ssl certificate from letsencrpyt for my local web server in windows 10 pro .
1. What should i do to get ssl certificate for my local web server as if i want to use it globally but web server should resolve my domain name from local dns server.I have tried to get ssl from letsencrypt but it ask me to add txt record in my dns server. How i can query and where i can add txt record(path)in my dns server. I dont want to use self-signed certificate  .
Web server: IIS 10 version in windos 10 pro
Dns server (BiNd 9): Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Thank you

Comment: Is your DNS server reachable from the Internet? Do you own the domain? Have you considered [one of the Let's encrypt clients for Windows](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/)? You can use a well-known URL published on your webserver as well.

Comment: DNS Server is reachable from internet. We own the domain name. I was using acme.sh for ssl. but it doesnt work. Can you help me out to get https locally.

Comment: If noone else comes along, I'll write up an answer later today. But I would really suggest to look into a Windows client, as the certs are needed on the windows machine running IIS, and automation is a key concept in LE...